# How to order sections in React Native ListView

Tags: react-native

I followed the example [here](https://medium.com/@darylrowland/reactnative-listview-with-section-headers-99a6714282c3) to create a ListView with sections. In my case each section maps to a date and each item is a reminder with a time. How do I make sure that the sections and items will get rendered in chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by sorting the items first. Here's the [code](https://github.com/lyahdav/qreminders-rn/blob/c00bcb66f39b844258aa533e7858df8030b6775c/components/scheduled-reminders-list.js#L44).